# How to extract image link from JSON in Flutter - Regex

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am a beginner in Flutter.  I was making a note-taking app, which contains [flutter_quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill). When I save the data into JSON, I got this data.

`[{"insert":"Ttttttt\n"},{"insert":{"image":"/data/user/0/com.example.notes/app_flutter/image_picker49200670200148407.jpg"}},{"insert":"\n\n"}]`

I just need the .jpg file data part - **/data/user/0/com.example.notes/app_flutter/image_picker49200670200148407.jpg**, How to get that? Using Regex?

Comment: Read this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-parse-json-in-flutter-for-beginners-8074a68d7a79)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  var l = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    {"insert": "Ttttttt\n"},
    {"insert": {        "image":"/data/user/0/com.example.notes/app_flutter/image_picker49200670200148407.jpg"}
    },
    {"insert": "\n\n"}
  ];

  var imageElement = l.firstWhere((element) =>
      element["insert"] is Map && element["insert"].containsKey("image"));
  var image;
  if (imageElement!=null) image=imageElement["insert"]["image"];
  
  print (image);
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

loop all insert then check, have key "image" so get that value

Comment: Your answer requires more detail. Some code (or pseudo-code), for example.